# issue with set default date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: html, jquery, datepicker

I have set datepicker which is given below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true
    }).datepicker('update', new Date());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="birth_date" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I want to set default date because I want to set this date picker in update data page.

so that I have to set one dynamic date

for that I have search and try many ways like

```
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2006, 11, 24));
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('update');
        $('#datepicker').val('');
```

and `$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", date);` this also

but this setdate() is not working

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0):

With your code, the date picker seems working as expected. Did you include the jquery path in your code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$(function() {
   // $("#datepicker").datepicker({
  //    autoclose: true,
  //    todayHighlight: true
  //  }).datepicker('update', new Date());
  //});
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2006, 11, 24));
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('update');
});
```

```html
<!-- Include jquery path -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="birth_date" readonly />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```